# Play framework - Using anorm with Option[LocalDate] \ Option[LocalDateTime]

Tags: scala, datetime, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am trying to define a nullable date field in postgres, while using anorm as connection to the database.

I am trying to update an entry:

```
def update(id: Long, startTime: Option[LocalDate]){
   SQL("""UPDATE my_table
        |SET start_date = {start_date}
        |WHERE id = {id}
      """.stripMargin)
      .on(
        'id ->id,
        'start_date -> startDate,
      ).executeUpdate()
 }
```

But I get a compilation error, looks like anorm can't handle Option[DateTime], although when I configured a parser it works form me:

```
val parser: RowParser[Info] = {
  get[Long]("id") ~
  get[Option[DateTime]]("start_date") map {
  case id ~ startTime => Info(id, startDate)
}
```

}

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a `import JodaParameterMetaData._`

Comment: @Lars Arnbak what about Option[LocalDate], need to import something else?

Comment: or Option[LocalDateTime]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating to anorm2.4 (with play 2.4): ToStatement\[T\] and ToStatement\[Option\[T\]\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809995/migrating-to-anorm2-4-with-play-2-4-tostatementt-and-tostatementoptiont)

Comment: @cchantep this did not fix my problem. You must add the relevant implicit definitions for anorm to be able to process LocalDate. I edited my solution also to include the ParameterMetaData class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play + Anorm + Postgres - load json value into a case class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924041/play-anorm-postgres-load-json-value-into-a-case-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added my own implicit definitions:

```
implicit def rowToLocalDate: Column[LocalDate] = Column.nonNull {(value, meta) =>
   val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
   value match {
      case ts: java.sql.Timestamp => Right(new LocalDate(ts.getTime))
      case d: java.sql.Date => Right(new LocalDate(d.getTime))
      case str: java.lang.String => Right(fmt.parseLocalDate(str))
      case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass) )
}
```

}

```
implicit val localDateToStatement = new ToStatement[LocalDate] {
    def set(s: java.sql.PreparedStatement, index: Int, aValue: LocalDate): Unit = {
       s.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(aValue.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()))
}
```

}

And the relevant ParameterMetaData

```
implicit object LocalDateClassMetaData extends  ParameterMetaData[LocalDate] {
   val sqlType = ParameterMetaData.DateParameterMetaData.sqlType
   val jdbcType = ParameterMetaData.DateParameterMetaData.jdbcType
}
```

That made the trick

Comment: Yea that will work.

However should be able to do

`val parser: RowParser[Info] = {
import JodaParameterMetaData._
  get[Long]("id") ~
  get[Option[DateTime]]("start_date") map {
  case id ~ startTime => Info(id, startDate)
}`

And have the types you need.

Answer (score 0):

Related question, [Anorm compare/search by java.time LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335607/anorm-compare-search-by-java-time-localdatetime) what it worked for me is just update to new version (not-yet-release-one)