# Migrating to anorm2.4 (with play 2.4): ToStatement[T] and ToStatement[Option[T]]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4, anorm

Up until the anorm included with play 2.3, I could write the following:

```
implicit val arbitraryClassToStatement = new ToStatement[ArbitraryClass] {
  def set( 
    s: java.sql.PreparedStatement, 
    index: Int, 
    aValue: ArbitraryClass
  )
  : Unit = {
    s.setString(
      index, 
      ArbitraryClass.definingString
    )
  }
}
```

and this would help insert the

```
SQL("INSERT INTO SomeTable Values( {nonNullAc}, {possiblyNullAc} )" ).on(
 'nonNullAc -> ArbitraryClass( "abcd" ),
 'possiblyNullAc -> Option( ArbitraryClass( "abcd" ) )
)
```

meaning that both ArbitraryClass and Option[ ArbitraryClass ] would be satisfied by it. This seems to no longer be the case as I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : (Symbol, Option[models.Misc.Url])
[error]     (which expands to)  (Symbol, Option[java.net.URL])
[error]  required: anorm.NamedParameter
```

Can someone please point me to what's the right way to handle this? I'd want minimal duplication of code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `ParameterMetaData[ArbitraryClass]` for this to work

```scala
implicit object ArbitraryClassMetaData extends ParameterMetaData[ArbitraryClass] {
  val sqlType = ParameterMetaData.StringParameterMetaData.sqlType
  val jdbcType = ParameterMetaData.StringParameterMetaData.jdbcType 
}
```

Here I just retook the values of `ParameterMetaData[String]`

Comment: This looks helpful. Is there a detailed doc somewhere besides the API reference?

Comment: Unfortunately not really, there's only the link you put above

Comment: Unfortunately in such case, Scalac doesn't support the `@implicitNotFound` which would indicate more precisely the root cause.